# Handling Mutiple Values to display one in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, msbi

I had to display one value on the basis of expression i.e. If column value =1 Print Y, if value=0 print N if value='' print N and value=NULL print N on to the column.

I tried the Below Code

`=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!MyColumnName.Value),"N",IIF(Fields!MyColumnName.Value=1,"Y","N"))`

But this is not working for the NULL values and Blank values in the column.

Thanks in advance...!!

Comment: What is your dataset returning, strings or integers?  Can you share an example dataset, as I am unable to recreate the problem - your expression above works fine for integers (and nulls)

Comment: It's returning integers,My column returns values  0,1,but in some cases column is blank. For value 1 I want do display "Y" for 0 "N" and for NULL or blank I want to display "N"

Comment: Why is it "not working" for null or blank.  What is it doing instead?

Comment: In Case of blank values, on running my report that column display "#ERROR" instead of N, But its working fine for column having values 0,1,i.e for 1 it is displaying Y and for 0 it is displaying N, But that code is not able to handle blank or null value.

Comment: What is the database returning, can it return empty `''` as well as `null`.  If it can return `''` then this might be the error as it is comparing an empty character string to an Integer...

Comment: Yes database is returning empty '' ''. So what code is to write to handle empty values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that SSRS evaluates all potential paths of an expression before executing it.  Therefore, when it tries to compare `''` to the integer `1` it fails, reporting the `#Error`

To protect against this you can wrap your fields in a CStr (Convert to String), giving the expression

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!MyColumnName.Value),
     "N",
     IIF(CStr(Fields!MyColumnName.Value)=CStr(1),
         "Y",
         "N"
     )
 )
```

The example below shows the value for myColumnName, the result with your current expression, a description of the value it is evaluating, and then the result of the above expression in the final column

[image]

Hopefully this will assist you.  Let me know if you require further help, or have more questions on this.